# Relation between Atiyah-Singer and Atiyah-Hitchin-Singer index theorems

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, mathematical-physics

How do we go between Atiyah-Singer index theorem to the [Atiyah-Hitchin-Singer index theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/79638?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)?

What are the conceptual connections between the twos? And how are they reduced from one to the other?